# Bed frame corner piece snapped - how to remove remaining plastic?

Tags: bedroom, plastic

Please help me figure out how to get the remaining plastic out of the bed rail? The corner snapped and I ordered a new corner part but need the remaining plastic gone

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: A pair of pliers to wiggle it out or a screwdriver jammed into the plastic to lever it out.  I think the main problem is them using hollow plastic in the first place for a structural piece.

Comment: That's a completely absurd "design" for a bed frame. Expect failures to continue until you get fed up and replace it with something that can stand the forces involved in that joint, which that hunk of plastic (and the 3 others like it, presumably) won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to grab the protruding edges with some vice grips or other type of pliers and pull that piece straight out. A sharp chisel could be used to pry it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a heat gun or hair dryer to heat up the end of the bar and the plastic piece inside it, then use a screwdriver to pry the plastic part on at least one side so that one side of the "square" is majorly indented.  Then you should be easily able to pull it out with pliers, or maybe even just the screwdriver you already have out.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the corner piece from the *other* end of the bed rail and send something through to push or knock the broken piece out.

A broom stick, a pill bottle filled with coins, a C or D battery, etc. Just find something that fits in the bed rail but won't fit through the broken piece. Hold the bed rail vertical and shake it up and down until your messenger taps the broken piece out.